# Why does git fetch remote branch always give me master?

Tags: git, branch

I have machine1 with git repo `client`, which has branches `master` and `fixes_v3`.  I have machine2 and no matter what combination of things I try it pulls a branch and names it `fixes_v3` but has the content of `master`.  e.g.:

`git clone git+ssh://user@machine1/home/user/client` gives me this

`git pull` gives me this

`git branch -a` then `checkout` the remote `fixes_v3` gives me this

`git fetch` gives me this

As well as various other combinations of these things, often starting over, aggregated from various SO questions, manuals, official documentation, etc.  I don't even know where to begin researching this without having to learn git from scratch for the nth time.

How to get the code in `fixes_v3` instead of just an improperly named branch `fixes_v3`?

Edit for requested output:

```
um@machine2:~/client$ git show-ref
ae10bcf7e15a4e251b50e8bc2eae3e5a2bc25b63 refs/heads/fixes_v3
ae10bcf7e15a4e251b50e8bc2eae3e5a2bc25b63 refs/heads/localfixesv3
ae10bcf7e15a4e251b50e8bc2eae3e5a2bc25b63 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ae10bcf7e15a4e251b50e8bc2eae3e5a2bc25b63 refs/remotes/origin/fixes_v3
ae10bcf7e15a4e251b50e8bc2eae3e5a2bc25b63 refs/remotes/origin/version3
um@machine2:~/unrollclient$ git ls-remote origin
um@machine1 password: 
ae10bcf7e15a4e251b50e8bc2eae3e5a2bc25b63    HEAD
ae10bcf7e15a4e251b50e8bc2eae3e5a2bc25b63    refs/heads/fixes_v3
ae10bcf7e15a4e251b50e8bc2eae3e5a2bc25b63    refs/heads/version3
7bd4490e8f98d29c5e82f473d1b04e542b67dec0    refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
16c7b55e2ea3e26c2f8faccd43e1c0db9620008a    refs/remotes/origin/Testing
a7a5642f6766332910c2c9005e8aafaf456f1f58    refs/remotes/origin/john
7bd4490e8f98d29c5e82f473d1b04e542b67dec0    refs/remotes/origin/master
ae10bcf7e15a4e251b50e8bc2eae3e5a2bc25b63    refs/remotes/origin/version3
um@machine2:~/client$ git remote show origin
um@machine1's password: 
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git+ssh://um@machine1/home/um/client
  Push  URL: git+ssh://um@machine1/home/um/client
  HEAD branch (remote HEAD is ambiguous, may be one of the following):
    fixes_v3
    version3
  Remote branches:
    fixes_v3 tracked
    version3 tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    fixes_v3     merges with remote fixes_v3
    localfixesv3 merges with remote fixes_v3
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    fixes_v3 pushes to fixes_v3 (up to date)
```

Comment: From the clone on machine2, please post the output of `git show-ref` and `git ls-remote origin`.

Comment: Does this have any output (on your local machine)? `git log refs/heads/fixes_v3...refs/remotes/client/vixes_v3`?

Comment: Can you post the output of `git remote show origin`?.

Comment: @CharlesBailey - added requested output

Comment: @KarthikBose - added requested output

Comment: Your description doesn't match what you've posted. `machine1` doesn't have a branch called master; it has branches called `fixes_v3` and `version3`, both at the same commit. Why do you believe you are getting the content of master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question turned out to be even dumber than I thought.  Changes in fixes_v3 branch were not committed...  after re-reading the git pro guide I was able to understand git well enough to troubleshoot such a basic step. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

get the remote branch fixes_v3 from origin repo

```
git fetch origin fixes_v3
```

Create a branch

```
git checkout -b myLocalFixes_v3 origin/fixes_v3
```

Should do the trick

Explanations of what you are doing

```
git clone git+ssh://user@machine1/home/user/client
```

You're cloning the repo locally, by default, your local repo will be checked-out on the HEAD revision of the remote repo. Which by default is master

```
git pull
```

Git pull (without options) will fetch then merge the default tracking branch onto your current branch. As you were locally on master, which was originated/tracked the remote master branch, then it will fetch (download in the cache) the remote master branch, then merge it on your current branch which is master.

```
git branch -a then checkout the remote fixes_v3 gives me this
```

The checkout is the tricky part. The checkout I gave you should work. I did wrong checkout in the past too because I didn't get all the subtleties. If you do

```
git checkout -b origin/fixes_v3
```

It will create a local branch called "origin/fixes_v3" which is based on master

```
git checkout -b origin/fixes_v3 master
```

Same here

```
git checkout -b origin/fixes_v3 origin/fixes_v3
```

It will create a local branch called "origin/fixes_v3" which is based on origin/fixes_v3 the remote "fixes_v3". You shouldn't do it though, because git will have problems figuring out after which "origin/fixes_v3" it is : the remote branch, or the local branch named with a "/" in it ?

```
git fetch
```

Git fetch only downloads the remote branches/commit in your local cache. It will do nothing else, no merge, no checkout, no rebase.

If your remote name is : origin, it will download the cache in the .git/refs/remotes/origin/ directory (I simplify)
So you will have .git/refs/remotes/origin/master and .git/refs/remotes/origin/fixes_v3.
When you will do a git checkout -b origin/fixes_v3 origin/fixes_v3
It will create a .git/refs/head/origin/fixes_v3 based on .git/refs/remotes/origin/fixes_v3, but then you will have conflict in names because won't figure if the origin/fixes_v3 means the remote on the origin remote, or the local branch named origin/fixes_v3

Comment: Nope.  I'm still seeing the master branch's clone after following your first two steps.

Comment: As said by Charles Bailey, you don't have the content of master on your clone. You have the content of (remote) version3 in your local branch fixes_v3 (which is the same as localfixesv3). The only other branches that are different than yours are the remote branches of the origin remote on machine1, like the branches : master, Testing, john